# what is the best query for tags and other related table

Tags: mysql, tags

I want to build a query to be suitable for searching in the book.title and the tag.tag
I also want a suitable for counting rows for search query for pagination

Here is my db schema and data

```
-- Table structure for table `book`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
`book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
ALTER TABLE `book`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`);


-- Dumping data for table `book`
INSERT INTO `book` (`book_id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Alice Journey'),
(2, 'Rody Journey'),
(3, 'My Journey to Amsterdam'),
(4, 'How to train your ketty'),
(5, 'The red fox');

-- --------------------------------------------------------


-- Table structure for table `tag`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
`tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
ALTER TABLE `tag`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`);



-- Dumping data for table `tag`
INSERT INTO `tag` (`tag_id`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'pets'),
(2, 'tale'),
(3, 'Journey');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- Table structure for table `tag_book`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag_book` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `tag_book`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`,`book_id`);


-- Dumping data for table `tag_book`
INSERT INTO `tag_book` (`tag_id`, `book_id`) VALUES
(1, 4),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 5),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(3, 3);
```

search = 'rody'     // exists in book table

search = 'pets'     // exists in tag tab

search = 'journey'   // exists in book and tag tables

thanks

Comment: select book.* from book
join tag_book on tag_book.book_id=book.book_id
join tag ON tag.tag_id=tag_book.tag_id AND tag.tag like '%$q%'
where book.title like '%$q%'

Comment: And what is the problem with it?